# XCode: How To Adjust Items In A UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uistackview

How do I adjust the TextField inside my StackView to fill in the gap between it and the label that I also have placed in there? I'm using the Storyboard.

**Currently looks like this:**

[image]

**Desired look**:

[image: os]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by just using nested `UIStackView`.

Add a Horizontal `UIStackView` first with spacing as 15 and distribution and alignment as Fill.

Inside it add two vertical `UIStackView` with both set to fill equally as the distribution and alignment as Fill. The spacing can be set to 10.

Inside the first vertical one add two `UILabel` and inside the second one add two `UITextField`.

[image]

And this will result in:

[image]

The labels will expand to fit the largest label.

Comment: Hey! It worked to the point where I have both labels lined up perfectly with their TextField. But still the TextField is very narrow and is not wide at all. It's pretty much the same width as the labels. How do I make the width of the TextField appear as yours in your image?

Comment: @Julian Did you add the constraints to the outer most `UIStackView`? Like the leading and trailing to the superView and a vertical constraint? It might not look proper on the storyboard but running the application will render it properly like the image.

Comment: I had done that, but I guess I had inadvertently done it to one of the inner StackViews which is why it didn't work. I did it again and it worked. Thank you so much!